# mysql query on the same column filtered by 2 different values

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products and I know for certain that there i s a product (ID= 18) that is belonging to category number 2, has a tag named "color" having value "jeans" and a tag named "fabric" having value "denim".

Product, products tags, products images, product options are different related tables that I am trying to join this way:

```
SELECT *, p.id as pid FROM prodotti_immagini pi 
LEFT JOIN prodotti p ON pi.prodotto = p.sku 
LEFT JOIN prodotti_opzioni po ON po.prodotto = p.id 
LEFT JOIN prodotti_tags pt ON pt.prodotto = p.id 

WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 
AND pt.tag = 'colore' 
AND pt.val_it LIKE '%jeans%' 
AND pt.tag = 'tessuto' 
AND pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Instead of getting the product id=18 I get an empty recordset.
But if I delete one of the clause on the tag, it works perfectly. This is the working one (where I have only filtered by fabric or "tessuto" in italian)

```
SELECT *, p.id as pid FROM prodotti_immagini pi 
LEFT JOIN prodotti p ON pi.prodotto = p.sku 
LEFT JOIN prodotti_opzioni po ON po.prodotto = p.id 
LEFT JOIN prodotti_tags pt ON pt.prodotto = p.id 

WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 
AND pt.tag = 'tessuto' 
AND pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' 
GROUP BY p.id
```

what's wrong in having 2 checks on the same column? What's the logic behind it? Thank you

Comment: A where clause on a left outer joined table (pt) renders that outer join as an inner join. Change "WHERE" to "AND" to see what I mean. Also, a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions is often a bad idea.

Comment: I have changed the WHERE in a AND and I get all the products. So how should I filter those products according your experience? I group the query by p.id, else I get N products*their related results (images or options or tags)

Comment: I don't understand. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a precedence between the column pairs, try this:

```
WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 
AND (
           ( pt.tag = 'colore' AND pt.val_it LIKE '%jeans%' )
       OR  ( pt.tag = 'tessuto' AND pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' )
)

GROUP BY p.id
```

**EDIT**: Other way, using the joins:

```
SELECT *, p.id as pid FROM prodotti_immagini pi 
LEFT JOIN prodotti p ON pi.prodotto = p.sku 
LEFT JOIN prodotti_opzioni po ON po.prodotto = p.id 

LEFT JOIN prodotti_tags pt ON 
    pt.prodotto = p.id 
    AND  ( pt.tag = 'colore' 
    OR  pt.val_it LIKE '%jeans%' 
    OR  pt.tag = 'tessuto' 
    OR pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' )

WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 

GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query show me products both with tag 'colore'='jeans' but no tag 'tessuto' AND products with tag 'tessuto'='denim' but no tag 'colore' ?? I know, my question is a mess...

Comment: Assume this: `int a = 3; if ( a ==3 and a == 4) ...`- this would always evaluate to false, since a variable (column) can only have one value in one row. Your query as in the question will never show any record. Please try to describe in normal words, what rows you want to select - and keep in mind that people tend to say "and" wheroften boolean " OR " is meant ...

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 
AND pt.tag = 'colore' 
AND pt.val_it LIKE '%jeans%' 
AND pt.tag = 'tessuto' 
AND pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' 
GROUP BY p.id
```

By this query condition , you are taking a row with value `pt.tag = 'colore' AND pt.tag = 'tessuto'` , which is **self contradictory**.

That's why empty set.

Then how can a row can have two different(`tessuto & colore`) values,where it can contain only one(either `tessuto  OR colore`)

So you should be looking something like this(see `OR` in `pt.tag` & `pt.val_it`)

```
WHERE pi.principale = 1 AND p.disponibile=1 
AND categoria = 2 
AND (pt.tag = 'tessuto' OR pt.tag = 'colore' )
AND (pt.val_it LIKE '%denim%' OR pt.val_it LIKE '%jeans%')
GROUP BY p.id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's what I thought, but how then? Supposed that product has 2 type of tags, each one having its own value, how can I query the db in order to get the exact match?

Comment: yes i can. The recordset is lmost the desired one. I'd say we can be happier now. I'll try to fit this query in order to narrow the results